# How to upgrate ASP.net application developed in visual studio 2005 to visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2005

I attempted to use old asp.net application (developed in vs 2005) in VS 20017 by creating both solution in vs 2017 and  website in IIS 10. it allows me to built but got error "missing MIME type" when I executed in VS 2017.

can you instruct how I can use old asp.net application developed from VS 2005 in VS 2017, where my environment is win10+iis10+ MS sql 2012

I expect asp.net application developed in VS 2005 (WIN 7 32bits) can be re-complied & executed in VS 2017 (WIN10 64bits) and hosted in IIS 10 with .net framework 4.6.1

Comment: Are you trying to run the application using IIS Express and Visual Studio 2017 or using IIS? Also, share complete error details and/or screenshot

Comment: if you are not change the asp.net version then you only need to setup the iss correctly to run your site